# Ubuntu boot is slower than Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7

One of the reasons I installed Ubuntu (Wubi installer) was for a supposedly quick boot time. My boot time with Windows 7 is about 20-25 seconds, while my boot with Ubuntu is 30-40. I judged the boot times from the time after I selected the operating system on the initial selection menu and the grub menu, respectively.

This is even after following all sorts of online guides to improve it. I've done driver profiling (and yes, I remembered to remove the "profile" edit in the grub file afterwards), I've cut a fair few startup programs out, and I've installed the preload package. But I'm still getting startup rates phenomenally slower than Windows 7.

Any help here?

Comment: `wubi` is always slow . Its because wubi creates virtual disk.  Windows 7 may also be supported some rapid boot function by the manufacturer.

Comment: In my experience, Ubuntu boots about as fast as W7 even when installed to its own partition.

Comment: I suggest doing a full install of Ubuntu.  It's faster than Wubi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can improve boot speed for Ubuntu.

1. get ubuntu certified hardware(or try :D)
2. get an ssd
3. limit start up services
4. don't use wubi

Boot time on Linux is an important feature especially on a laptop.  I remember when decreasing the boot up time was an important feature of Ubuntu just a few revisions ago and while I may not be able to tell you exactly the reason why your ubuntu installation boots slowly I can tell you mine boots quickly.

This might help figure out the offending application that is hurting your boot time

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After you reboot look in /var/log/bootchart

I believe you can also use log viewer.

After you get that post your results and I will try and help you.

Also post your output of

```
dmesg
```

Comment: Increasing the boot up time never has never been a feature persued by Ubuntu. :~) They've tried decreasing or reducing it, or in other words, making it boot faster, but never slower.